Error loading SSH private key with ssh-add: "invalid format" during Docker build
Question:
I am trying to pass an SSH private key to ssh-add during a Docker build but I’m encountering the error:
Copy code
Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format
Steps:
I load the private key from a file using cat.
I try to pass the key to ssh-add using:
bash
Copy code
echo "$github_pv_key" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
The key is in the following format (printed with echo for debugging):
What I’ve tried:
Using sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\n/g' to restore newlines, but still get \n in the key content.
Using tr -d '\r' to remove carriage returns, but the key format still appears invalid to ssh-add.
The error message:
vbnet
Copy code
#15 0.394 Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format

I'm trying to use an SSH private key during a Docker build by passing it as an argument to ssh-add, but I'm encountering the following error:
Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format.

`The key is being passed as an environment variable, but it seems that the format is being altered (especially newlines) when passing it to ssh-add. I have tried using tr -d '\r' and sed to handle the newlines, but the error persists.`

How can I properly pass the SSH private key to ssh-add without getting the invalid format error?

You might try passing it as a base64 encoded string or something.  So base64 -w 0 private_key to encode, and base64 -d to decode. This can often be used to get around weird escaping issues.

it is working, when I used
So base64 -w 0 private_key to encode, and base64 -d to decode.
